# Removing a key with empty values from a map so they are not included in a query of a REST GET request

Tags: groovy

I have a Query class which holds the queries i can send like so:

```
Class Query {
   Integer product_id
   Integer collection_id
   Integer id
}
```

I use object mapper to convert my Query object to map like this:

```
def q = new Query(product_id: 12345)
Map <String, Object> toMap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue( q, Map )
```

Which then in turn i pass on my RESTClient so it is included in the request

```
def client = new RESTClient ('http://somewebsite.com')
client.get(path: 'somePath/anotherPath.json',
           contentType: ContentType.JSON,
           query: q)
```

After i send the request, the empty keys in the query map are also sent in the request which causes problems to the response

```
GET somePath/anotherPath.json?product_id=12345&collection_id=&id=
```

As the title says, is there a way to remove keys with empty values in map so they are not included in the request when you send a REST GET request. I want it to be like this:

```
GET somePath/anotherPath.json?product_id=12345
```

Where the key with empty values (collection_id and id) is not sent in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the annotation @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)

```
Class Query {

   @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
   Integer product_id
   ...
}
```

See documentation [here](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html)

Comment: Thank you! i am having troubles with annotations because im just starting out. it is now working how i want it to work. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `ObjectMapper` have any parameter which would disable exporting nulls?

If not you may do:

`Map <String, Object> toMap = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(q, Map).findAll { it.value != null }`